# Angular 7 + localize-router: test language switching

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm quite new to Angular and now stuck with the following issue.

I use [localize-router](https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router) along with `ngx-translate` to have paths like `http://myapp/en/home` and `http://myapp/fr/home`. Language switching is done via router links:

```
<a mat-button [routerLink]="'/en'" class="en-link">en</a>
<a mat-button [routerLink]="'/fr'" class="fr-link">fr</a>
```

Also I subscribed to `LangChangeEvent` in `AppComponent`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected and now I'd like to test language switching:

```
const routes: Routes = [{path: '', component: AppComponent}];

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let translate: TranslateService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        LocalizeRouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
          parser: {
            provide: LocalizeParser,
            useFactory: LocalizeHttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [TranslateService, Location, LocalizeRouterSettings]
          }
        }),
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: TranslateHttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        })
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  });

  it('should switch language', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const selector = By.css('.fr-link');
    const frLink = fixture.debugElement.query(selector);
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      frLink.nativeElement.click();
      const injector = getTestBed();
      const translate = injector.get(TranslateService);
      expect(translate.currentLang).toBe('fr');
    });
  });
});
```

After link click I get the error from other component test:

```
DashboardComponent should create
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'fr'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'fr'
  at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js:2469:1)
  at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js:2450:1)
  at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js:34:1)
  at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:80:1)
  at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:60:1)
  at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:80:1)
  at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:60:1)
  at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:80:1)
  at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:60:1)
  at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js:61:1) thrown
```

`DashboardComponent` is a container component that is normally bound to empty path in `AppRoutingModule`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [{path: '', component: DashboardComponent}]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to me localize-router does not work with RouterTestingModule. I can't find a sample on their github-repo either providing a full module sample. They test the service instead, maybe you could take a look at it: [localize-router/tests](https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router/blob/master/tests/localize-router.service.spec.ts)